# Building a 18’ diameter 2x4 ring

Tags: pool

I am building a 2x4 ring for my 16’ round pool. I want to build a 18’ diameter 2x4 ring to place in the ground to contain the sand the pool will sit on. How to I calculate the correct beveled angles along with board length to accomplish this?

Comment: Either dig our your high school trig book or draw the circle to scale.

Comment: It completely depends upon the width of the boards....did you say 2/4's?  That's going to mean a LOT of cuts/joints, why not go wider, like 2x6 or 2x8.

Comment: How close to true circular do you expect to get?  If you create a polygon it would be a simple calculation based upon the number of sides.

Comment: Am I missing something where is the length of the boards and are they being laid flat or on edge and a band to hold them like a wooden tank or hot tub.

Comment: see https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/14499/6806

Answer (score 2):

The circumference of a circle is Pi x the circle's diameter, so your 18' circle is approximately 678.5".

2x4's are 3.5" wide, so that requires 193 of them, with ~3" of extra space distributed between them.

A full circle is 360°, so each 2x4 needs a bevel angle of 360/193 = 1.86°, or a 0.9° bevel cut on each edge.

Probably not worth the trouble to do that - just use the 'raw' 2x4's as they are.

If you used 2x6's instead, then you'd need 123 of them (also with a little gap to fill at at the end), with an overall bevel of 2.9° or about 1.5° on each edge - still probably not worth the effort to do the bevel cuts.

With 2x8's you're down to 90 of them (with a little gap), 4° overall bevel or 2° each edge... I probably still wouldn't bother to cut bevels on these.

Comment: This seems to be assuming OP wants to stand the boards on end, but since they ask for the length of the boards I presume they want to create some kind of polygon with boards laid on the long edge.

Comment: @Khrrck - yeah that's a possibility - but the OP would have to specify the number of sides and/or preferred rough board length...

Comment: @ErikPotter - can you tell us which way you're planning and give more detail?

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to build a polygon to approximate a circle. There are online calculators for that -- I searched for "polygon generator" and found one at [blocklayer.com](https://www.blocklayer.com/trig/polygonseng.aspx). This one has controls you can adjust to make a polygon having from 3 to 50 sides.

If you adjust those controls to draw a tetrakaidecagon (14 sides, obviously!) with radius of 8' 11-9/16" (diameter about 3 hairs less than the 18 ft you requested) then the sides have length 3' 11-7/8", which is just about right to cut two sides per 8 ft long 2x4 and so uses materials efficiently.

This tool works with zero-width lines, of course, so you'll have to do a little work on your own to decide where the real-world width of the 2x4 should go (fully inside or outside the line, or centered on it, etc).

Here is a screen shot of the calculations for the above-mentioned size.

[image: blocklayer.com screen shot]